# Advanced file type guesser

Tags: c++, c, linux

How does (exactly) utility like UNIX `file` command guess the file type?

Are there any source-codes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It uses various heuristics, mainly signatures which are described in a configuration file.

```
man -s 5 magic
```

will gives the file format.

Answer (score 4):

It looks at the magic number in the first few (2-4?) octets of the file.

Comment: it's a bit more sophisticated than that, but you got the basic principle right. +1.

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED Yes, that is a gross simplification. The answer of @AProgrammer is correct.

Answer (score 4):

[Here](http://www.darwinsys.com/file/) it is and quite interesting :)